# How to include HTML content programmatically?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a method at Spring controller which returns HTML code. How can I inlude this HTML code in DetailsDialog? By the way this method returns HTML codes as `Byte Array`.

```
<p:dialog id="DetailsDialog" header="Details" widgetVar="DetailsDialogWid">
    <!--HTML PAGE-->
</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply include your HTML content with an `h:outputText`, but you will need to change your output content in `String` before.

**Bean code :**

```
public String getHtmlContent()
{
    return String(getByteArrayHtmlContent(), CHARACTER_ENCODING_OF_HTML);
}
```

Note that you must generally specify the character encoding of the byte array to correctly convert it to a string. `CHARACTER_ENCODING_OF_HTML` might be `"US-ASCII"`, `"UTF-8"`, `"ISO-8859-1"` etc. depending on what the byte array contains.

**View code :**

```
<p:dialog id="DetailsDialog" header="Details" widgetVar="DetailsDialogWid">
    <h:outputText value="#{yourBean.htmlContent}" escape="false" />
</p:dialog>
```

Note the `escape="false"` that prevent conversion to HTML entities.

More info : [JSF outputText example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-outputtext-example)

Comment: Using `new String(byte[])` is almost always wrong, because it uses the default character encoding, which might be anything. I took the liberty of editing that into the answer.